# If $\sum \|f_i\|$ converges and $\sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i$ exists in a normed function space, do we get for free that $\|\sum_{i=1}^n f_i - f\| \to 0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

Let $(V,\|-\|)$ be a normed function space, and suppose that $(f_i)_i$ is a sequence of elements of $V$ so that $\sum \|f_i\| < \infty$. Further suppose that this data implies that $f = \sum f_i$, where $\sum_{i=1}^n f_i \to f$ **pointwise**, is an element of $V$. Then I would think that we can show immediately that $\sum_{i=1}^n f_i \to f$ in norm, as:
$$\left\|\sum_{i=1}^n f_i - f \right\| = \left\|\sum_{i=1}^n f_i- \sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i\right\| = \left\|\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty f_i\right\| \leq \sum_{i=n+1}^\infty \|f_i\|$$
which is sensible, as we can show that any tail of $\sum f_i$ is in $V$ as well. However, as $\sum \|f_i\| < \infty$, it follows that the right-hand-side goes to zero as $n \to \infty$, thus proving that $\sum_{i=1}^n f_i \to f$ in norm.

**Here is my question:** Have I made a mistake in the above reasoning?

The reason I am suspicious is because whenever I have seen an example of this situation in books (e.g., showing $L^p$ is a Banach space), the author shows convergence in norm using some other method dependent on the properties of the norm being considered. However, I cannot determine where the reasoning could break down.

Comment: The definition of infinite series is such that $f = \sum_i f_i$ **means** that $\left\| \sum_{i=1}^n f_i - f\right\|\to 0$.

Comment: Apologies if my post was unclear. In this case, $V$ is a function space (e.g., $C([0,1])$) and $\sum_i f_i$ is the *pointwise limit* of the partial sums. This does not tell us immediately that $\sum_i f_i \to f$ in the norm of the space. I've bolded the word "pointwise" in the post now.

Comment: You need completeness. In a complete normed space, a norm-convergent series of functions (i.e. absolutely convergent series) also converges in the normed space. All counterexamples that do not assume completeness have to exploit a sequence $f_n \in V$ such that $\sum \|f_n\|$ is finite and yet $\sum f_n \not \in V$ which that often will imply $\| \sum f_n \| = \infty$ but not always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is a gap. The inequality
$$ \|\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty f_i\|\leq \sum_{i=n+1}^\infty \|f_i\| $$
is not justified in your argument, because the series on the left hand side converges just pointwise. The inequality itself is trivial if the partial sums converge in $V$, but it is not trivial at all assuming only pointwise convergence. If your function space satisfies the condition that any pointwise converging series satisfies the above inequality, then your argument works. Otherwise, you have no way of proving it in general, and in fact the inequality could be false for some function spaces.

---

**Edit.** An example where such a step is justified would be any Banach space $X$ that satisfies the following: if $g_n\to g$ in $X$ and $g_n\to h$ pointwise, then $g=h$. In fact, in that case the series
$$ \sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i $$
converges in $X$ to some $g$ since absolutely convergent series converge in Banach spaces, and $f=g$ if the above property holds. In particular, the series converges to $f$ in the norm of the Banach space. Such spaces are, for example, $C([0,1])$, Lebesgue spaces $L^p(\Omega)$ with $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^d$ (in that case though it would be more appropriate to speak about almost everywhere convergence), ...

Comment: Ah, because the proof of that inequality relies on the hypothesis that the partial sums $\sum_{i=n+1}^k f_i$ converge to $\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty f_i$ *in norm*, not just pointwise! Thank you, this clarified the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is too long for a comment, but is only a partial answer. The point Ben is making, is that your mistake lies in the step $$\left\|\sum_{i=1}^n f_i - f \right\| = \left\|\sum_{i=1}^n f_i- \sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i\right\|.$$
The point here is that we do *not* yet know that $f= \sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i$ in $V$. Sure, we know that for every $x$ in our domain, $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^nf_i(x)$, but that doesn't mean we can replace $f$ by $\sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i$ within the norm, because by doing that you are implicitly assuming that $\left\|\sum_{i=1}^n f_i-f\right\|\to 0$.  $\sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i$ only makes sense as an entity in $V$ by defining it as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^nf_i$, with the limit taken in $V$.

Comment: I see. So if we define $g$ to be the function so that $g(x) = \sum_{i=n+1}^\infty f_i(x)$ for every $x$, we do not know a priori that $\|g\| \leq \sum_{i=n+1}^\infty \|f_i\|$?

Comment: @William, correct.

Answer (score 1):

The key step is $\left\|\lim\limits_{m \to \infty} \sum\limits_{i=n+1}^m f_i\right\| \leq \sum\limits_{i=n+1}^\infty \|f_i\|$. And in general pointwise convergence doesn't have to do anything significant with norm.

Let $X$ be space of sequences that are eventually $0$ with norm $\|x\|_X = \sup_n \frac{|x_n|}{2^n}$ and $Y$ be $X \times \mathbb R$ with norm $\|(x, r)\|_Y = \|x\|_X + |r|$. Let $V$ be space of sequences that are eventually constant with norm $\|v\|_V = \sup_n \frac{|v_n - \lim v|}{2^n} + |\lim v|$ - it's indeed norm, as $V$ is isomorphic to $Y$ via $f(y) = f((x, r)) = (x_1 + r, x_2 + r, \ldots)$.

Now, let $f_i = e_i$ and $f = (1, 1, \ldots)$. Then $\sum f_i \to f$ pointwise, $\sum \|f_i\|_Z = 1$, but $\left\|\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n f_i - f\right\| > 1$, so series doesn't converge in norm.

Answer (score 1):

I made a comment but I think this needs expanding. So here it is the expanded comment.

**Theorem.** Let $(v_n)$ be a sequence of vectors in a *complete* normed space such that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \|v_n\|$ converges. Then there is a $w$ such that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n v_i \to w$ in the normed space.

*Proof.* Immediately from the triangle inequality $\left\|\sum\limits_{i=n}^{n+p} v_i\right\| \leq \sum\limits_{i=n}^{n+p} \|v_i\|$, so the sequence of *partial sums* of $(v_n)$ is fundamental and therefore converges by completeness. QED

By notation, one often writes the vector $w = \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty v_n.$  However, when the vector space is that of functions, one can also use the notation $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ to mean pointwise limit. Thus, pointwise convergence of series of functions can have two completely different meanings. One being of simple convergence and the other of normed convergence. In function spaces, normed convergence and pointwise convergence can differ substantially.